# Prevent streaming play stop when screen goes off Kitkat

Tags: android, streaming, android-4.4-kitkat, playing

We are streaming to play sound in App but due to Kill/Draining battery feature in Android Kitkat 4 currently playing is stopped when screen goes off. How to overcome this or handle this and keep playing in screen off mode also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your streaming playback should be managed by a foreground `Service`, one that is maintaining a partial `WakeLock` (to keep the CPU going normally) and, if needed, a `WifiLock` (to keep the WiFi radio on).